# Getting an error trying to install a particular gem 'oily_png (1.2.0)' MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, osx-elcapitan

I'm on mac OS X El Capitan and after trying to run bundle install I get the following error:
[image: Terminal Error after running bundle install]

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: Have you recently installed 10.11? Or upgraded it or Xcode?  Try 'xcode-select --install ' in the terminal and see if that helps

Comment: I have recently installed 10.11, maybe a couple weeks ago now. I'm trying to install and I hope it'll fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Doon, this solved the issue! Want to post it as an answer so I can verify it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Mac anytime you upgrade Xcode or the operating system, there appears to be a chance of the command line tools being removed.

```
 xcode-select --install
```

in the terminal  window, will install the tools, this can also be done inside the xcode application.

```
[~] xcode-select -h
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example,
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  --install                   open a dialog for installation of the command line developer tools
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
```

if you have more than one set of tools installed (such as beta version) the `-s, --switch` flag is also helpful to get it pointed to one you want to use (or if the version it was pointed to was removed)